# Very basic regular expression, what does it mean?

Tags: regex

Ok, a friend of mine confronted me with a regular expression he found in a piece of code and I am not experienced at all. I tried to figure it out and I really think that it is quite basic, but I have trouble.

The expression is: `^(.*?){0,1}>$`

So this is what I gathered from various tutorials and definitions:

- `^` stands for "start" and `$` for end, so expression between those must describe the full string in order to be selected.
- `*?` is a lazy operator (meaning it first tries to take 0 of the preceeding character, if that doesn't match, it takes one, two, three, etc).
- `(.*?)` so this must mean "takes as few characters as possible".
- `(.*?){0,1}`: Now the trouble beginns for me. "Take as few characters as possible, zero times or once"?
- `^(.*?){0,1}>$`: "Take as few characters as possible, zero times or once, with the character > afterwards followed by the end"?

That would basically mean "select everything, if a > is at the end of the string"? I am confused... I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this (I guess very basic) problem...

EDIT: Ok, to prevent missunderstanding, the regex is used in this context:

```
.replace(/^(.*?){0,1}>$/,"$1/>");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is equivalent to the following:

```
^(.*)>$
```

Whoever wrote it in the first place was probably in a hurry, and didn't realize they were putting so much extraneous stuff in there.

---

After clarifying your use case, just use this:

```
.replace(/>$/, '/>');
```

and it'll add a slash before the closing `>` tag (if there is one).

---

If you want to add the slash only if it's not there yet, use this:

```
.replace(/([^\/])>$/, '$1/>');
```

Comment: So it basically means "string with > at the end"?

Comment: No, it's not equivalent. These regexes capture different things.

Comment: @brimborium - Correct, but it also [captures](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) everything but that last `>`.

Comment: If used with `(?:)`, definitely. But sometimes regexes are used not only in tests.

Comment: It is actually used like this: `.replace(/^(.*?){0,1}>$/,"$1/>");`. I made an edit to the question to clarify. Did not know that this is important.

Comment: @brimborium - Exactly. All this RegEx does, is add a slash before the closing `>`.

Comment: @raina77ow - How do you figure?

Comment: @JosephSilber Thanks! Can you include that comment into your answer?

Comment: @brimborium - After providing your use case, I was able to further simplify it. See my amendment.

Comment: @JosephSilber Ok, so if I change the code to `.replace(/^(.*?)/{0,1}>$/,"$1/>")`, it will still do the same, but will in fact not put a second slash in there, if there is already one?

Comment: @brimborium - If you want to add the slash only if it's not there yet, use the method I just added.

Comment: @JosephSilber Sorry for the delay. Thanks a lot for your answer, it was really helpful.